# Get information out of a JSON like file in c# (.NET 4.8)

Tags: c#

I'm currently still learning c# and im trying to find the best method to get the information out.
Tried Regex and even thought of using JSON but im pretty sure there is a simpler method.
I have data like this:

```
Main_name = {
    # Comment
    # Comment
    # Comment
    type1 = uselessname_importantNumber                                (e.g. ryu_3)
    type2 = "path" # Comment
    type3 = name
    type4 = true

    type5 = {
        name2
        name3...
        # Comment
    }
}
```

My objective is to store the values: Main_name, importantNumber, path, name, true, list of names in type5 in a List.

Currently im doing

```
TechData = new List<ClassTech>();

            string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");

            foreach (string pathsl in paths)
            {

                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(pathsl))
                {
                    string line;
                    int i = 0;
                    string[] words;



                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {


                        if (line.Contains("{") == true && !line.Contains("#"))
                        {

                            // Get's the name
                            words = line.Split('=');
                            TechData.Add(new ClassTech(words[0].Trim(' '), "None", -1, null, "None", null, true));


                            // In {}
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if ((Regex.Match(line, @"\bera\b")).Success && (TechData[i].era == -1) && !line.Contains("#"))
                                {
                                    words = line.Split('=');
                                    TechData[i].era = words[1][words[1].Length - 1] - 48;

                                }
                                else if ((Regex.Match(line, @"\btexture\b")).Success && (TechData[i].texture == null) && !line.Contains("#"))
                                {
                                    words = line.Split('=');
                                    TechData[i].texture = words[1].Trim(' ', '"');

                                }
                                else if ((Regex.Match(line, @"\bcategory\b")).Success && (TechData[i].category == null) && !line.Contains("#"))
                                {
                                    words = line.Split('=');
                                    TechData[i].category = words[1].Trim(' ');

                                }
                                else if ((Regex.Match(line, @"\bcan_research\b")).Success && (Regex.Match(line, @"\bno\b")).Success && !line.Contains("#"))
                                {
                                    TechData[i].canResearch = false;

                                }
                                else if ((Regex.Match(line, @"\bmodifier\b")).Success && !line.Contains("#"))
                                {
                                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                    {
                                        if (line.Contains("}")) { break; }
                                        else if (line.Contains("="))
                                        {
                                            TechData[i].modifiers.Add(line.Trim(' '));
                                        }
                                        else { }


                                    }

                                }
                                else if ((Regex.Match(line, @"\bunlocking_technologies\b")).Success && !line.Contains("#"))
                                {
                                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                    {
                                        if (line.Contains("}")) { break; }
                                        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                                        {
                                            TechData[i].restrictions.Add(line.Trim('\t'));
                                        }
                                        else { }
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (line.Contains("}") == true)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                }

                            }
                            i++;
                        }


                    }





                }
            }
```

The problem is if the data becomes bigger, it will start to become harder and harder so my question is: is there a simpler way to do it and if possible faster?

Data example

```
sericulture = {
    # Unlocks Mulberry Groves PM on Rice Farms
    era = era_1
    texture = "gfx/interface/icons/invention_icons/sericulture.dds"
    category = production
    can_research = no
    
    modifier = {
        building_silk_plantation_throughput_mult = 0.25
        
    }
}

enclosure = {
    # Unlocks construction of Farms and Plantations
    era = era_1
    texture = "gfx/interface/icons/invention_icons/enclosure.dds"
    category = production
}

manufacturies = {
    # Unlocks Mercantilism Law
    # Unlocks Food Industry, Textile Mills, Furniture Manufacturies, Glassworks, Tooling Workshops, Paper Mills
    era = era_1
    texture = "gfx/interface/icons/invention_icons/manufacturies.dds"
    category = production
}

shaft_mining = {
    # Unlocks Coal Mine, Iron Mine, Lead Mine, Sulfur Mine
    era = era_1
    texture = "gfx/interface/icons/invention_icons/shaft_mining.dds"
    category = production
    
    unlocking_technologies = {
        enclosure
        manufacturies
    }
}

atmospheric_engine = {
    # Unlocks Motor Industry
    # Unlocks Atmospheric Engine Pump PM in Coal Mine, Iron Mine, Lead Mine, Sulfur Mine
    era = era_1
    texture = "gfx/interface/icons/invention_icons/atmospheric_engine.dds"
    category = production
    
    unlocking_technologies = {
        shaft_mining
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the data *have* to be represented like that, rather than as actual JSON? Using a standard file format would make it *much* simpler to work with.

Comment: You can learn from Microsoft: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: @JonSkeet it is represented like that but i think converting it to JSON and then using JSON would be a lot worst.
What i'm doing is reading from a file that could change the data

Comment: If the structure is sufficiently simple that you could write entirely general code to convert it to JSON, then use the wealth of tooling available to work with JSON, I think you'd be in a *much* better position. All the code aimed at parsing *very specific values* would just go away. You could deserialize straight to classes if that would be useful. You could integrate with other tools easily. We can't give any code for a conversion like that though, as we don't have nearly enough details of the file format.

Comment: @JonSkeet accually i dont really know how to convert to JSON because of the comments, my method would be .Split(' ') and then recreate the hierarchy but the comments make it so much harder and if they have an = every thing is done

Comment: Well we can't help you with that because we don't have any details of the file format, just one example. I still strongly suggest that should be your approach though - I think your current approach will be really brittle. Hint: what happens if the file contains `texture = " category "` or `category = " texture "`? Do you think your code will do the right thing in both of those situations?

Comment: @JonSkeet Added some files and yeap it will fail and because its so weak im trying to find a better solution

Comment: Fwiw, you can regex replace all comments fairly easily or just pass every line to a fn like this (though this will catch quoted '#' as well: `string StripComments(string line) => line[line.IndexOf('#')..];`

Comment: er, fixed version, previous logic I posted was outright wrong: `string StripComments(string line) { int idx = line.IndexOf('#'); return idx != -1 ? line[..idx] : line; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broadly agree with @Jon Skeet's suggestion to convert these files to JSON. If you can do that at the source, do it.

If not, you'll either have to convert it yourself, or parse the data some other way.

Regardless, if you want this to be expandable, your goal should be to be able to get this data into C# without relying on beforehand knowledge of any property names.

I've put together a parser based on the example files you've left above. It's not perfect, but it should be a strong starting point:

[The full project, and the primary parsing logic](https://github.com/John-Paul-R/so-object-parser-thing/blob/master/ObjectParserThing/ObjectParserThing.cs)

It works by parsing the input file to a string-keyed dictionary containing values of `Dictionary<string,object?>`, `List<string>`, or `object?`.

Note: if you want to convert this JSON data to C# objects *afterwards*, go for it. It'll be much simpler once it's in JSON form, since there are many tools for that.

### Example usage

#### SourceFile.txt

```
Main_name = {
    # Comment
    # Comment
    # Comment
    type1 = ryu_3
    type2 = "path" # Comment
    type3 = name
    type4 = true

    type5 = {
        name2
        name3...
        # Comment
    }
}
```

#### Program.cs

```cs
var outVal = new ObjectParserThing.ObjectParserThing().ParseFile("sourceFile.txt");

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(outVal, new JsonSerializerOptions {
    WriteIndented = true,
}));
```

#### Output

```json
{
  "Main_name": {
    "type1": "ryu_3",
    "type2": "\u0022path\u0022",
    "type3": "name",
    "type4": "true",
    "type5": [
      "name2",
      "name3..."
    ]
  }
}
```